# "Here" at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: word-order

Are both sentences correct or start below sentences with "here" is impossible and "here" at the beginning of positive sentences is used only in sentences like "Here is your key" and it's all?

> Here were too many tourists in summer.
>
> There were too many tourists here in summer.

Comment: It's no longer idiomatic to start an utterance with adverbial ***here*** (locational, meaning ***in this place***) . The usage only only survives in "mock archaic" facetious usages such as ***Here be dragons***, and formal frozen forms such as ***Here lies John Smith*** on a gravestone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is wrong.

Such a sentence starts with "There is", "there are", "there were", "there will be", and so on, when you mean to say:

"I am going to make a statement about something I have not yet mentioned: ..."

"There were" + a statement about tourists, in this case: "too many tourists (were) here in summer".

"There" does not mean "in that place" in this instance, so do not confuse it with the instance of "here", which *does* mean "in this place".

Hence:

"There were too many tourists here in summer"

actually means the same as.

"Too many tourists were here in summer."

Answer (score 0):

The *presentative* "there is/are/was/were" is invariable, apart from the verb form (and indeed, many people say "there's" even for plural complements).

It does not have a deictic function: if you want to locate the sentence you need to add a deictic:

> There were too many tourists there last Summer.

(The first "there" is unstressed and has a reduced vowel. The second has at least some stress, and a full vowel.

So,

> There were too many tourists here last Summer.